# Selection.Filldown

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to fill down data from lastrow of column B to I up to the last row of column J. I have tied the below code but its not working.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim lrow As Long

    LW = Worksheets("master log-1").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
    NW = Worksheets("master log-1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox "Last Row: " & LW
    MsgBox "Last Row: " & NW

    Worksheets("master log-1").Range("B" & NW, "I" & NW).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B:I" & lrow), Type:=xlFillCopy

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe `Range("B:I" & lrow)` to `Range("B" & LW, "I" & LW)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you have been trying to do. Please try.

```
Sub AppendRows()

    Const NumRows As Long = 3           ' enter how many rows to append

    Dim Ws As Worksheet                 ' always declare the sheet you are working on
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Ws = Worksheets("master log-1")
    ' make sure the row is the same for both ends of the range
    Set Rng = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 8)
    Rng.AutoFill Destination:=Rng.Resize(NumRows + 1, Rng.Columns.Count)
End Sub
```

Your code wants a pre-determined last row. I thought that is a derivative and you really want to add a certain number of rows. Should I be mistaken the required change to the code would be miniscule.

Comment: last row for column J :X is below to last row of column B :I  by "N" nos  of rows....just want to copy the data from column B to I of last row and paste till the last row of J:I

Comment: Is the last row for the AutoFill equal to the last row in another column? If so, which column. Or can you determine the desired last row as a difference from the existing last row in any other column? If so, which column and which difference?